# How to associate a number to a button and get that number when the user clicks on the button?

Tags: unity

I am creating buttons for each level through script as shown below

```
private void CreateLevelButtons()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_levels; i++)
    {
        Button button = Instantiate(button_prefab);
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().fontSize = 12;
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Level " + i.ToString();
        button.transform.SetParent(content.transform, false);
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickLevelButton());
    }
}
```

In OnClickLevelButton() function I want to determine the level number of the button that was clicked. Is there a way to associate a number to a button so that i can access that number later when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: I assume to i variable is similar to the number you want to pass along here, is it not possible to provide this variable on the `OnClickLevelButton(i)` method?

Comment: What is holding you from creating a component with an integer field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you have to take care of the [**closure problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp). In order to avoid this, create a temporary variable like this:

```
private void CreateLevelButtons()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_levels; i++)
    {
        int index = i ; // Create variable to avoid closure problem
        Button button = Instantiate(button_prefab);
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().fontSize = 12;
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Level " + i.ToString();
        button.transform.SetParent(content.transform, false);
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnClickLevelButton( index ));
    }
}

void OnClickLevelButton( int i )
{
    Debug.Log("Button #" + i + " has been clicked!");
}
```